# "no screens found" on Live CD with Nvidia Optimus

Tags: boot, nvidia, graphics, uefi, nvidia-optimus

I have a Lenovo y410p, and I am trying to install Ubuntu 13.10 in EFI mode side-by-side with a Windows 8 installation on a GPT partition. I have already disabled secure boot, and I have the LiveCD image running off a USB flash drive in EFI mode.

When I get to the GRUB environment, I have to modify the kernel arguments to put `nomodeset=1` or the screen will be turned off when the kernel starts.

`lsmod` shows that the following modules are loaded for video:

```
i915
nouveau
```

The former is just the usual Intel graphics driver, and the latter is the open source NVIDIA driver.

When X starts, in `/etc/X11/Xorg.0.log` it reports that a screen was found but it was not properly configured, and then it shows "no screens found".

Starting with `nomodeset=1` in Install Ubuntu instead of Try Ubuntu works fine.

After installation, the same issue occurs as on the live environment. No dice. Not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the screen was showing up black was because KMS (Kernel Modesetting) wasn't turning on the backlight for the Intel-backed screen. In Optimus, the Intel device gives the image to the screen device, and the NVIDIA device simply acts as a pixel buffer generator and is not actually attached to the screen.

Open `/etc/rc.local` and add the following line before `exit 0`

`setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=30`

The `30` may be changed to any value between `00` and `FF`. 00 is Full Bright, FF is Full Dark.

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/157344/246852