# Resolve these startup errors

Tags: 14.04, startup, 14.10

i am getting the following errors at startup. can anyone tell me about them and how to fix them?

14.500214] [drm:cpt_set_fifo_underrun_reporting] *ERROR* uncleared pch fifo underrun on pch transcoder A

14.500214] [drm:cpt_serr_int_handler] *ERROR* PCH transcoder A FIFO underrun

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updated Intel display driver causing errors when booting](http://askubuntu.com/questions/507302/updated-intel-display-driver-causing-errors-when-booting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot Ubuntu from your Live Disk and download [Ubuntu Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and start the `Automatic Repair` to resolve your issue.