# Hide Ubuntu boot errors and show splash screen instead

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, plymouth

Whenever I boot Ubuntu, instead of getting the purple splash screen, I get a couple of errors, one of which is:

```
[drm:intel_pch_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]]
```

Things I've done:

- Set kernel parameters to `quiet splash` (using `grub-customizer`)
- disabled "show menu" and "look for other operating systems" (`os-prober`?)
- ran: `sudo apt install plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo`
- Tried `boot-repair` on a live CD

I'm 90% sure the issue isn't with grub, but with plymouth, is there any way of just hiding those messages?

The laptop is a Dell inspiron 17R 5720 with both integrated graphics (Core i5 3210M) and dedicated (GeForce GT 630m)

`uname -a` outputs `Linux MattTop 4.4.0-34-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 27 16:06:39 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: What is the problem ? Plymouth (boot splash) not working ? What video card do you have ? Does this help ? http://askubuntu.com/questions/136593/how-can-i-fix-broken-i915-drivers-for-intel-gpus

Comment: Plymouth works, for about a split second, after it shows the errors. I've done some research, and seen that the errors aren't that much of an issue. All I want to do is hide them and just show the boot splash.

Comment: This may be a kernel bug - please [edit] your question and include the output of `uname -a`